# XML parsing for particular attributes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, xml-parsing, android-xml

How can i parse this xml file on android to get Url of large image

```
<image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/62210477.png</image> <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/62210477.png</image>
<image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/62210477.png</image>
```

What is best method to access url of image size="large" on Newer Android Version like ICS and JellyBean
**Edited question  **
as link provided in answer I made some changes according to my xml file now i i get data but i want to access url of large image what modification i need to do to get large image url

code to modify (i think )

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    elementOn = true;
    if (localName.equals("artist"))
    {
        data = new XMLGettersSetters();
    } else if (localName.equals("image")) {
        /** 
         * We can get the values of attributes for eg. if the CD tag had an attribute( <CD attr= "band">Akon</CD> ) 
         * we can get the value "band". Below is an example of how to achieve this.
         * 
         * String attributeValue = attributes.getValue("attr");
         * data.setAttribute(attributeValue);
         * 
         * */
    }
}
/** 
 * This will be called when the tags of the XML end.
 **/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    elementOn = false;
    /** 
     * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
     * */ 
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
        data.setTitle(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("listeners"))
        data.setArtist(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url"))
        data.setCountry(elementValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
        data.setCompany(elementValue);
    }
/** 
 * This is called to get the tags value
 **/
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (elementOn) {
        elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        elementOn = false;
    }
}
```

Please help me 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Sax or dom parser for this purpose,I recommend Sax parser because it's less memory footprint and fast.

For more detail with example check this [link](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)

```
@Override 
  public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

      //do some checking.

      if(atts.getValue("size").equals("large")&&localName.equals("Image"))
      {
            //do some action
      }; 

  }
```

Comment: I go with your link and download it and made some modification according to my link but now i got url of small image . what code i need to change to get large image url? please check main question i just edit it now

Comment: dude i am stuck and i am helpless can you just help me can you just write simple code which retrieve large image from this link
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=cher&track=believe

Comment: Site related to file sharing and personnel sites are blocked here.You succeed in getting all image Urls right Now you need only filter urls  with size large right?

Comment: no i dont get all 3 image link ..i just get 1st link which is small one..and i want to write code for lasfm for search artist..and grab photo from there

Comment: Please post complete format of xml file you get, I assume this is not complete xml

Comment: I xml is long ..you can do one thing just go to lastfm web site there is api option at down of page, left hand side there is artist option into that search artist and there is XML link with sample api key so you can take a look at there 3 image attributes or give me email id i will main you code and xml both thank you for help

Comment: Dude I figure out the problem.. Thanks for your help and support..I got all 3 string than i take into array and display 2nd array to image view ..thank you so much

Comment: blocked -:),sax xml parser scan the xml from top to bottom so start tag and it's value will get in the startElement method in handler class you need to write your own logic to store these values.you may create List of data each data items is added in startElement function

Comment: yup i did that way only to store all links of image thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String URL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=akon&api_key=your_api_key";
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("album");

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        Log.e("name", parser.getValue(e, "name"));
        NodeList k = e.getElementsByTagName("image");
        for (int j = 0; j < k.getLength(); j++) {
            Element e1 = (Element) k.item(j);
            if(e1.getAttribute("size").equals("large"))
            Log.e("ImageURL", parser.getValue(e1, "image"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
    String textVal = "";
    NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
        if(el.getFirstChild()!=null)    
        {
            textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    return textVal;
}

or try using ele.getAttribute(tagName)
```

Enter your element node and tagname "image" in the above method...

Comment: I follow this tutorial now i got the data from xml but how can i access url of large image..how to access particular attribute ..please check the code in main question i just edit it

Answer (score 0):

Parse the url of the image from the url of the xml into a string and use that string for whatever purpose.

You can have a look at jsoup from jsoup.org. I am using that in several projects and am happy with it.